# Do some clean-up in preferences file on update

Tags: android, updates

I'd like to change the name of a parameter in my preferences file. The new version of my app expects the new name. If an older version is already installed, it will have created a preferences file that will contain the old parameter name. After updating, the newest version will look for the new name, not the old. Therefore I need to change the old name to the new.

One obvious solution is for the new version to check the parameter name in the preferences file and change it if necessary. That could be done for example in the `onCreate()` method. But I would prefer to avoid the burden of doing that check every time the app is started. It would be better if it could be done just once, when the app is updated.

So what I want is to do the clean-up of the preferences as part of the update process. Is it possible to run some Java code as part of the installation? Can the update process do something other than copy the new app files on the old ones? If not, is there any other way to do such changes to the preferences file on update? Note that, although I want to change the *name* of a parameter in the preferences file, I need to keep its *value*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On API12+ you can do your update work in some `BroadcastReceiver` registered for the Action `Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED

If you implemt the update there, you can drop all update calls in some place like `Application.onCreate()` for API12+.
So only old phones nee to check for updates on every start.

Comment: Thank you. So, how does my application receive the intent? I need to create a `BroadcastReceiver` and put the code in its `onReceive()` method, right? I don't follow your comment about `Application.onCreate()`

Comment: Yes, create a BroadcastReceiver, add it to the AndroidManifest.xml with an intent-filter for the given action. If you customize your `Application` class, you can make use of it's onCreate() call. In Application.onCreate(): check if you are on API11- AND if an update is needed. if so. do it.